# How to get file name using libcurl?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I use `libcurl` to download file, url may be like this below

```
url = "https://***.com/**/***/abc"
url = "http://***:8000/**/test.txt?***2484d197c16b2e"
url = "http://***:8000/**/test.txt"
```

It is troublesome to get its file name, so is there a way to get file name using `libcurl` when downloading it? My download code is below.

```
size_t writeData(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

int downloadFile(const char *url, const char *saveFile)
{
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *saveFd;
    CURLcode res;
   
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        saveFd = fopen(saveFile,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeData);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, saveFd);
        std::string strurl = string(url);
        if (strurl.find("https") != string::npos) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        }
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        
        fclose(saveFd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do the responses you receive include the `Content-Disposition` header?

Comment: @BradyDean How to get the responses?

Comment: @Yongqui I'm talking about the HTTP response headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION.html) to get a callback for each of the HTTP headers. You are looking for the header called `Content-Disposition`.

Comment: Just note that there is no guarantee that such a header will actually be provided. Typically, it is present only when the server provides a file intended to be downloaded rather than displayed. A text file is more likely to be displayed rather than downloaded.